# Prevent MPMusicPlayerController from playing next song in que

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am creating an app that has a playlist and uses the MediaPlayer library. When a song ends I don't want the next song to start. I tried to use the MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification to pause the music player when the song changes, but the song starts to play before I get the chance to stop it. I also tried to use KVO to track the changes to musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime, but I only receive messages when i manually change the playback time. I can't find any information about this problem anywhere.

Comment: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification  will notify you only after Item changes. Do you use setQueueWithItemCollection or setQueueWithQuery to set playlist? How many items are in it?

Comment: I use setQueueWithQuery to set the playlist and the number of items depends on how many songs the user adds. For the testing I use a playlist of 14 songs

Comment: What happens if the user switches your app to the background while the playlist is playing? I'd suggest creating a queue of 1 item at a time and give that to the musicplayer.

Comment: If the user switches the app to the background, the music stops playing, but everything else is normal, I believe. Thanks for the queue tip!

Answer (score 1):

In my app I have shuffle and repeat off, and create a queue with only one song in it, then send that to the music player. When the song finishes, there aren't any other songs in the queue, so it stops playing.

That being said, the latest iOS update has stopped reporting the correct playback state when the song finishes and is reporting it as paused when it used to be stopped. Not sure if that's a side-effect of the above method or not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling:

```swift
player.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
```

before adding the observers?